# Physics Engine (Collision Detection C#, GDI+)

Tags: c#, gdi+, physics, game-physics

I'm currently working on a 2D Game Engine in C# using GDI+ and have gotten to the point where I want to add simple collision detection.

So far, I can check whether or not my player has intersected with another game object using the code below:

```
public static bool IntersectGameObject(GameObject a, GameObject b)
{
    Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle((int)a.Position.X, (int)a.Position.Y, a.Sprite.Bitmap.Width, a.Sprite.Bitmap.Height);
    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle((int)b.Position.X, (int)b.Position.Y, b.Sprite.Bitmap.Width, b.Sprite.Bitmap.Height);

    return rect1.IntersectsWith(rect2);
}
```

That's fantastic and I'm happy that I've gotten this far, however I wish to find out whether or not my player has intersected with the top, bottom, left or right side of a game object so that I can stop my player from moving in that direction if say... he collides with a wall. How would I go about doing this? Can some one please help me :)

By the way, game objects have Bitmaps, that are all 32 * 32 pixels, so i don't need per pixel collision

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computing whether two rectangles intersect is just a matter of a few comparisons (I know you're already using `IntersectsWith`):

```
if (Left > other.Right) return false;
if (Right < other.Left) return false;
if (Top > other.Bottom) return false;
if (Bottom < other.Top) return false;
return true;
```

To determine the direction of the collision, you'll have to take into account the possibility that:

- one rectangle *completely contains* the other (collides in no direction)
- it might create a "plus" figure (collides in all directions)
- one corner of the rectangle could intersect with a corner of other corner (collides in two directions)

Anyway, to determine whether it has collided on the left side:

```
if (Right > other.Left && Right < other.Right && Left < other.Left)
{
    // the right side of "this" rectangle is INSIDE the other
    // and the left side of "this" rectangle is to the left of it
}
```

Last but not least, if you're computing this frame by frame, there's the possibility that an object might "jump over" the other. For more realistic physics you'd have to keep track of time and compute *when* it would intersect with (each edge of) the rectangle.

Comment: Although I've labelled this as the best answer, I've chosen not to go this route. However your answer is extremely informative.

Answer (score 1):

If you're processing frame by frame, a good choice could be storing the previous position `P0x,P0y` and the current position `P1x,P1y`.

[image]

Then, you can calculate a vector Vx,Vy and you can calculate the intersection point `Ix,Iy`. So you can get a more precise information about the collision.

Answer (score 0):

If you need collision detection you need a rigidbody, you normally move rigidbodies with physics. As far as I saw, it's possible to live problem with above code snippet. If your moving them with transform move you should mark as is kinematic. That means it will not be moved by physics but by transform.

A kinematic rigidbody which you want to move should be done during FixedUpdate to apply collisions properly.

if you would like to know which side you hit you may raycast to the object

This code snippet gives an example that shows a raycast you could perform on collision. Ultimately, which game engine have you been using?

```
//this ray will generate a vector which points from the center of 
 //the falling object TO object hit. You subtract where you want to go from where you are

 Ray MyRay = ObjectHit.position - ObjectFalling.position;


 //this will declare a variable which will store information about the object hit
 raycasthit MyRayHit; 

 //this is the actual raycast
 raycast(MyRay, out MyRayHit);

 //this will get the normal of the point hit, if you dont understand what a normal is 
 //wikipedia is your friend, its a simple idea, its a line which is tangent to a plane

 vector3 MyNormal = MyRayHit.normal;

 //this will convert that normal from being relative to global axis to relative to an
 //objects local axis

 MyNormal = MyRayHit.transform.transformdirection(MyNormal);

 //this next line will compare the normal hit to the normals of each plane to find the 
 //side hit

 if(MyNormal == MyRayHit.transform.up)
 {
 you hit the top plane, act accordingly
 }
 //important note the use of the '-' sign this inverts the direction, -up == down. Down doesn't exist as a stored direction, you invert up to get it. 

 if(MyNormal == -MyRayHit.transform.up)
 {
 you hit the bottom plane act accordingly
 }
 if(MyNormal == MyRayHit.transform.right)
 {
 hit right
 }
 //note the '-' sign converting right to left
 if(MyNormal == -MyRayHit.transform.right)
 {
 hit left
 }
```

Comment: You must not have seen my read my entire post, I'm writing my own game engine, in c# using GDI+

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understand this sentence "I'm currently working on a 2D Game Engine in C#" as being "I'm currently developing on a 2D Game Engine in C#"

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be an option to have 4 different objects each one on 1 side on your player object so depending on which side intersects with game object you could know which movement direction to prevent ?